# How do I fill an array of data with CoreData data?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am learning to use SwiftUI with Core Data.

I am trying to fill a Line Chart with saved weight data like below:

```
LineView(data: [0, 32, 445, 56, 99])
```

I’ve gotten as far as this but im getting an error on the "var locations = ..." line saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserWeight")
var locations = mocW.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [UserWeight]

for weight in weights {
    print(weights.userWeight)    
}
```

Any help on this and how i would populate the line chart with this data would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One of your tags is SwiftUI but you don’t mention it in your question and your code is Swift. So 1 if you’re using SwiftUI, you should consider using the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper.

Comment: If you read the Core Data Programming Guide for [FetchingObjects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html) you’ll see some detailed instructions.

Comment: Yes i am using SwiftUI sorry i should have clarified that. Thanks for your comment ill take a look! @andrewbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SwiftUI, I suspect that you are attempting to achieve the following...

```
struct YourView: View {

    @FetchRequest(entity: UserWeight.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: []
    ) var weights: FetchedResults<UserWeight>
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(weights) { weight in
            Text(weight.userWeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Core Data entities confirm to the `Identifiable` protocol, so you'e able to drop the `id:` parameter in the `ForEach` structure...

```
ForEach(weights) { weight in
```

Otherwise you'd need to use...

```
ForEach(weights, id: \.self) { weight in
```

*Note: As an aside, it would help us if you could provide more detail in your questions in the future. The more information you provide, the easier it is for the community to understand your issue and provide a suitable response. Remember that your question and our answers may not only help you, but also help others in the future as they visit the site looking for answers to their own problems.*

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let appDelegate =
      UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Memory>(entityName: "Memory")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "rating", ascending: false)
        var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %@", "image")
        
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        do {
            result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
```

"result" is an array of, in my case, Memory objects which are instances of NSManagedObject. To access properties and populate views I do this:

```
for memory in result {
        let value = memory.entityPropertyName
        
    }
```

I think this should be enough to get your started, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I should have clarified that i am using SwiftUI for this, will this change if your code will work? I cannot get to my computer for a while to check. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If `UserWeight` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, you should declare your fetch request as

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserWeight>(entityName: "UserWeight")
```

Or else as

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserWeight> = UserWeight.fetchRequest()
```

Then you can use the fetch like this, and the type of `locations` will be `Array<UserWeight>`.

```
let locations = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

I'm not sure where `executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)` comes from-- it's not a function defined by `NSManagedObjectContext` in Swift. It resembles the Objective-C version of the function, but in Swift it's different.

Comment: I should have clarified that i am using SwiftUI for this, will this change if your code will work? I cannot get to my computer for a while to check. Thanks for the reply!